# asp.net how to know when this tab selected

Tags: asp.net

This is my aspx code

```
<div id="tabs-1">
                <table id="BookingTable" runat="server" class="tableResultClass">
                    <tr>
                        <th>ID</th>
                        <th>PlanTime</th>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
            <div id="tabs-2">
                <div id="circleG" style="margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; padding-top: 50px; padding-bottom: 50px;">
                    <div id="circleG_1" class="circleG"></div>
                    <div id="circleG_2" class="circleG"></div>
                    <div id="circleG_3" class="circleG"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="tabs-3">

                <p>
                    Date:
                    <input type="text" id="datepicker" runat="server">
                </p>

                <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager" runat="server" />
                <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" UpdateMode="Conditional" runat="server">
                    <ContentTemplate>

                               <asp:Button ID="BookingForDate" runat="server" OnClick="BookingForDate_Click" Text="Search" />
                        <span style="color: red" id="errorDateMessage" runat="server"></span>
                        <div runat="server" id="circleG2" style="margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; margin-left: 400px; padding-bottom: 60px;">
                            <div id="circleG_1" class="circleG"></div>
                            <div id="circleG_2" class="circleG"></div>
                            <div id="circleG_3" class="circleG"></div>
                        </div>
                        <table id="DateBookingTable" runat="server" class="tableResultClass">
                            <tr>
                                <th>ID</th>
                                <th>PlanTime</th>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </ContentTemplate>
                </asp:UpdatePanel>
            </div>
```

It is simple code that have three `div` as tabs.

I want to know which tab is selected in a specific moment. how please?

#### I think it is something about session but I don't know what it is

Comment: Add extra class to each tab(div) like `selected` when you select and remove the same for other tabs, and use .selected to identify

Comment: @MuraliMurugesan the problem is that how to know `when to add that class`. if i knew when to add that class, i would know that this div has been selected. right?

Comment: How you are selecting the div? Ofcourse you need to set the display:block to the selected and for others display:none. Where you are doing this?

Comment: @MuraliMurugesan I am not doing that my friend. what I am doing is making a `href` on each `li`. when that href refers to that `div`

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:-

1) Declare a global variable.

2) Attach a `onClick` event for each div. Whenever this event is fired, set this global variable with the id of corresponding div.

3) Access this global variable in the required function.